# Scalameta Decl.Def not works on a trait def method

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scalameta

I'm use Scalameta(v1.8.0) annotation to a def declaration:

```
trait MyTrait {
  @MyDeclDef
  def f2(): Int
}
```

The annotation class defined just return input, as this:

```
import scala.meta._

class MyDeclDef extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    defn match {
      case defn: Decl.Def =>
        defn
      case _ =>
        println(defn.structure)
        abort("@MyDeclDef most annotate a Decl.Def")
    }
  }
}
```

some compiler error encounter:

```
Error:'=' expected but eof found.
def f2(): Unit
Error:illegal start of simple expression
def f2(): Unit
```

Besides, If I use `Decl.Var` to `var v2: Int` it works fine.

How to right annotate a trait `def`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with `scala-meta` before and tried your example. It looks like we have to implement this method in the macros. For example, if we specify a default implementation:

```
class MyDeclDef extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    defn match {
      case defn: Decl.Def =>
        val q"def $name(): $tpe" = defn
        q"def $name(): $tpe = 1"
```

we will be able to create an instance of `MyTrait` and print a value of the `f2` method :)

```
val x = new MyTrait
println(x.f2) // Prints 1
```

`var v2: Int` works fine, because it fits to `case _` in which we `abort` the compilation.

Comment: Your implementation works fine but I hope you can try my example. Besides, If you define `q"def $name(): $tpe"`, it will cause same problem as the question encountered.It seems a bug at [github issue](https://github.com/scalameta/paradise/issues/211)